# Python Pandas group by function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, max, min

I have this table

```
    uname   sid usage
0   Ahmad   a   5
1   Ahmad   a   7
2   Ahmad   a   10
3   Ahmad   b   2
4   Mohamad c   6
5   Mohamad c   7
6   Mohamad c   9
```

I want to group by uname and side, and have usage column =  `group.max` - `group.min`. But if group count is `1` return group `max`

the out put should be

```
    uname   sid usage
0   Ahmad   a   5
1   Ahmad   b   2
2   Mohamad c   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `agg` to grab `min`, `max`, and `size` of each group.
Then multiply `min` by `size > 1`.  When it is, it will equal `min`, else `0`.  Then subtract that from `max`.

```
d1 = df.groupby(['uname', 'sid']).usage.agg(['min', 'max', 'size'])
d1['max'].sub(d1['min'].mul(d1['size'].gt(1))).reset_index(name='usage')
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe better is use `d1['max'].sub(d1['min'].mul(d1['size'].gt(1))).reset_index(name='usage')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) difference [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) and [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html) if `length` is more as `1` else `max`:

```
df = df.groupby(['uname','sid'])['usage']
       .apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min() if len(x) > 1 else x.max())
       .reset_index()
print (df)
     uname sid  usage
0    Ahmad   a      5
1    Ahmad   b      2
2  Mohamad   c      3
```

I think instead `max` you can use `iloc` too:

```
df = df.groupby(['uname','sid'])['usage']
       .apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min() if len(x) > 1 else x.iloc[0])
       .reset_index()
print (df)
     uname sid  usage
0    Ahmad   a      5
1    Ahmad   b      2
2  Mohamad   c      3
```

Another solution with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html), which test [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['uname','sid'])['usage']
s = g.max()-g.min()
print (s)
uname    sid
Ahmad    a      5
         b      0
Mohamad  c      3
Name: usage, dtype: int64

print (g.size() == 1)
uname    sid
Ahmad    a      False
         b       True
Mohamad  c      False
dtype: bool

print (s.where(g.size() != 1, g.max()).reset_index())
     uname sid  usage
0    Ahmad   a      5
1    Ahmad   b      2
2  Mohamad   c      3
```